# Codeigniter - How to convert a html page to an image?

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter

I've a webpage, coded on **codeigniter** framework, which lists all available certificates. Then I can print a certificate by clicking on its name or by checking checkboxes if the user wants to print more than 1 certificates.

Currently what I do is just to view the html of the certificate, and the user had to right click on their browser and click on print. Which is fine for 1 page of certificate.

But when I've 2 or more certificates, the certificates aren't stack perfectly. As far as I know, I can't set the html page to be an A4 size print.

Codeigniter had an image manipulation library. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

But couldn't find what I wanted.

Is there a way to convert these html pages into image which I can later print those? Or should I try other libraries?

Answer (score 2):

I would use DOMPDF to create a PDF document. You can generate them the html as normal, then use the third parameter of the load view function to return the html for the PDF processing.

Something like this in your controller;

```
    $this->load->helper('pdf');
    $html = $this->load->view('certificate_view', array(), TRUE);
    $attachment_location = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/certs/'.$title.'.pdf';
    pdf_create($html, $title, $stream=FALSE, $orientation='portrait');
    // send open/save pdf dialog to user
    header('Cache-Control: public'); // needed for i.e.
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.'"');
    readfile($attachment_location);
    exit;
```

The Codeigniter DOMPDF library is [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PDF_generation_using_dompdf).

Comment: Currently all chosen certificates would be rendered into a single long html page. Wouldn't it be resource intensive if I were to print 500 certificates? Or should I loop the process to output pdf into a folder, then extract 1 pdf at a time to print?

Comment: I would do a single certificate view in a loop, with the last element a div that has a page break rule, to build the html

Comment: The solution that I came up with is to use tcpdf. Seems that it could withstand large amount of certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an html to image by using this simple [tutorial](http://buffernow.com/html-to-image-php-script/). It uses imagick and no gd library.

Comment: I've already advised you to show some code examples on your answers and it seems that I wasn't the only one. I will start voting down your answers like this one.